# Multilist: Pointer pointing to another node

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

im trying to make a multi-list where user input is (1,350) where 1 is the student and 350 is the class. I have created a linked list for student and class but im not sure how i would link the node of student 1 to node of class 350.

is the link `Class *classNode` valid?

Would i make a new node with student and class and at it into a combined list?

The output should be:

```
class 350: students 1, 4, 6, ....
```

or

```
student 1: classes 350, 389, 991...
```

```
struct Student {

        int sID;
        Class *classNode;  

        Student *nextS;
};

struct Class {

        int cID;
        Student *studentNode;  

        Class *nextC;
};
```

Comment: As exposed, the `struct Class` is not known when used in `struct Student { }`. To fix this, you could insert a forward declaration: `struct Class;` (before). This would be sufficient for a usage as pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Student class is fine if a student is related to iff a class. But I guess a class has more than one student so

```
struct Class {
   int cID;
   Student **studentNode;

   Class *nextC;

}
```

would be better.

What you need to do create a class first than a student for that class.You can use nextS to search and add new student.

According to your edit I changed my answer and here a example code to make it look better and work better you need to put real effort.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student {
    int sID;

    struct Class **classNode;

    struct Student *nextS;
} ;

struct Class {
    int cID;
    struct Student **studentNode;

    struct Class *nextC;

};

int main() {

    struct Class *class1 = (struct Class*) malloc(sizeof(struct Class));
    class1->cID = 1;
    class1->studentNode = (struct Student**) malloc(sizeof(struct Student*)*2);
    class1->nextC = (struct Class*) malloc(sizeof(struct Class));
    class1->nextC->cID = 2;
    class1->nextC->studentNode = (struct Student**) malloc(sizeof(struct Student*)*2);
    struct Student *student1 = (struct Student*) malloc(sizeof (struct Student));
    student1->sID = 1;
    student1->classNode = (struct Class**) malloc(sizeof (struct Class*)*2);
    student1->nextS = (struct Student*) malloc(sizeof (struct Student));
    student1->nextS->sID = 2;
    student1->nextS->classNode = (struct Class**) malloc(sizeof (struct Class*)*2);
    class1->studentNode[0] = student1;
    class1->studentNode[1] = student1->nextS;
    class1->nextC->studentNode[0] = student1;
    class1->nextC->studentNode[1] = student1->nextS;
    student1->classNode[0] = class1;
    student1->classNode[1] = class1->nextC;
    student1->nextS->classNode[0] = class1;
    student1->nextS->classNode[1] = class1->nextC;
    printf("student1  classes ");
    printf("%d   ", student1->classNode[0]->cID);
    printf("%d\n", student1->classNode[1]->cID);

    printf("student2  classes ");
    printf("%d   ", student1->nextS->classNode[0]->cID);
    printf("%d\n", student1->nextS->classNode[1]->cID);

    printf("class1  ");
    printf("%d   ", class1->studentNode[0]->sID);
    printf("%d\n", class1->studentNode[1]->sID);

    printf("class2  ");
    printf("%d   ", class1->nextC->studentNode[0]->sID);
    printf("%d\n", class1->nextC->studentNode[1]->sID);

    
    return 0;
}
```

I create two classes and two students and pointed them to each other. But I really wonder how you ended up in a bad data structure.

Comment: So when I do that, and run I get a lot of errors :                                                                 
 error: redefinition of ‘class classList’ class classList{. error: #include nested too deeply